# Maven package is not packaging my classes

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven to generate my program into a JAR but everytime I run it, it does not package any of the classes I have made. I have looked into the pom file and made some changes to the mavan-jar-plugin goal to point towards `jar` but it still continuously ignores my classes. Here is what my pom file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>tmp2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dcm4che</id>
            <url>http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-audit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-image</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-iod</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                     <execution>
                <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>DicomTesting.menu</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                           </execution>
                     </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>DicomTesting.menu</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When running mvn package or mvn clean package, I get:

```
C:\temp\workspace\TrialTester>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - tmp:tmp2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\temp\workspace\TrialTester\src\mai
n\resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\temp\workspace\TrialTester\src\tes
t\resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default}]
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\temp\workspace\TrialTester\target\tmp2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ja
r
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: assemble-all}]
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/slf4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] Building jar: C:\temp\workspace\TrialTester\target\tmp2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-ja
r-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/slf4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/dcm4che2/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/dcm4che/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 24 12:12:36 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/252M
```

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

UPDATE: Here is what the folder looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the list of dirs in `C:\temp\workspace\TrialTester>`

Comment: Where are your source files?  Maven is strict about these things, and expects your source files to be under `\src\main\java`.

Comment: I added a pic of what the directory looks like

Comment: @bot do you have any other suggestions, I just added sourceDirectory and it is still not packaging correctly. `<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/DicomTesting</sourceDirectory>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a lot of customizations that aren't necessary; remove them. Most likely, your problem is that your source files aren't under `src/main/java`, which is the default location where Maven expects your sources to be found. You can override this location by setting the `sourceDirectory` element.

Comment: Was going to post this as an answer but there are a couple of other reasons for this issue. Would be a good idea to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: What would be considered unecessary in the pom file?

Comment: And also, I tried to add the sourceDirectory to my build section and I keep getting hit with a build failure...